# How can i do, when scraping using xpath give no result

Tags: python, xpath

i've been using python3.8 and its module-urllib.

My goal is to get the text

"""Dapps Built for 50 Million Users - 8 Cases You Should Know about ICON"""

from html below.

```
<div class="article-sec" data-v-727113bd="">
 <div data-v-3b154919="" data-v-727113bd="" class="item item">
  <a data-v-3b154919="" href="/article/dapp-com-list-icon" target="_blank">
    <div data-v-3b154919="" class="image" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://dappimg.com/media/image/article/1fe42da2f8ca44dab2884690624ecfa7.jpg&quot;);"></div>
    <div data-v-3b154919="" class="combine-info">
      <div data-v-3b154919="" class="name">Dapps Built for 50 Million Users - 8 Cases You Should Know about ICON</div>
    </div>
    <div data-v-3b154919="" class="time">Mar 18 · 1220 Views</div>
  </a>
 </div>

xpath-1 : xpath('//div[@class="article-sec"]')
xpath-2 : xpath('//div[@class="article-sec"]/div')
```

The 'xpath-1' gives me an element.
But 'xpath-2' gives me no result.

The most wanted question is *How can i get the text?*

And secondary question is *Why doesn't 'xpath-2' give me a result?*

Here is the url : https://www.dapp.com/community

Thank you guys for answers in advance.

[image: XML Data]

Comment: Copying the xml into the question is much better than posting an image because then we can experiment with it. Best of all is a smaller hacked up exmaple xml that demonstrates the problem but doesn't leave us searching through reams of data.

Comment: Please provide HTML code in a text format.

Comment: When you get a `'//div[@class="article-sec"]'` element, print out its subtree. Its possible that the inner document is generated by javascript and wouldn't be in an `urllib` fetched version. In that case, try `selenium` to pull the page in through a browser.

Comment: @tdelaney i add a webpage link that  i scraped, and html structure.  Thank you for mention. i'll try with selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go deeper to get the text. If you just want the first title :

```
(//div[@class="article-sec"]//div[@class="name"])[1]/text()
```

If you want all titles:

```
//div[@class="article-sec"]//div[@class="name"][1]/text()
```

EDIT : Without Selenium, in R, you can do something like :

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
page=getURL("https://www.dapp.com/community")
parse=htmlParse(page)
titles=xpathSApply(parse,"//div[@id='__nuxt']/following::script[@type]",xmlValue)
result=unlist(str_extract_all(gsub(',"influencers.*','',titles),'(?<="title":").+?(?=")'))
```

Output :

[image: R Titles]

Otherwise, just get the json located in the script tag (type = text/javascript) of the webpage and parse it with an appropriate tool :

[image: Json]

Comment: The XPath expression is correct. As stated by @tdelaney, you'll probably have to use Selenium to get the data. Post is edited with some options.